# Sleeping kinematic rigidbody not calling OnCollisionStay

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have an interaction system which relies on an OnCollisionStay event to be called for the duration of the overlap.

The physics system is forcing the Rigidbody to sleep and the following has no effect:

- calling `rigidbody.WakeUp()`
- setting `rigidbody.sleepThreshold = 0;`
- calling `rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.zero);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that kinematic Rigidbodies are far more keen to stay asleep than their non-kinematic bretheren. Calling the following will ensure your kinematic Rigidbody does not go to sleep.

```cs
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position);
}
```

Keep in mind that this is circumventing a built-in optimization so only use when nessecary.